# ALAssetsLibrary is Nil, Can't Save Video To Photo Album

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alassetslibrary

I am having trouble using ALAssetsLibrary to write a video from a URL into my saved photos album. I am not sure how to go about initializing the library correctly. Apple's reference to ALAssetsLibrary doesn't really explain how to do so. I am getting the usual unwrapping nil value error.

Could anybody point me in the right direction here?

I'll gladly take any tips as well as to how I can make things more efficient, or guides and tutorials that could teach me how.

here is my code that tells the camera to take a picture or start recording. As of right now, I am only focused on recording, since it will be the main feature of my application.

```
/**************************************************************************
DID PRESS CAPTURE
**************************************************************************/
@IBAction func didPressCapture(sender: AnyObject) {

    if self.takingVideo == true {

        //------ MAKE SURE WE ARE NOT ALREADY RECORDING ------
        if self.weAreRecording == false {

            println("Taking a video")

            //------ MAKE SURE THE DEVICE IS AUTHORIZED TO TAKE A VIDEO ------
            if self.deviceAuthorized == AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {

                println("Device is authorized to take video")

                println("Getting Video Output Path")

                //------ GRAB THE OUTPUT FILE URL TO SAVE TO PHOTO ALBUM ------
                let outputPath = "\(self.documentsPath)/output.mov"

                self.outputFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
                self.session.startRunning()

                println("Starting to record to output path")

                if let movieOutput = self.movieFileOutput {

                    movieOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(self.outputFileURL!, recordingDelegate: self)

                }
                else {

                    println("Movie file output is NIL!!!!")
                }
            }
            else {

                println("Device is not authorized to take video")

            }

        }
        else {

            //------ STOP THE VIDEO, PROCESS THE VIDEO HERE ------
            println("Stopping the video")

            println("Stopping the session from recording")

            //------ STOP RECORDING AND SAVE TO VIDEO TO PHOTO ALBUM ------
            self.session.stopRunning()
            self.movieFileOutput!.stopRecording()
        }
    }
    else {

        //------ HANDLE TAKING A PICTURE HERE ------
        println("Taking a picture")
    }
}
```

and here are my delegate functions that are called when the video starts and finishes recording.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {

        println("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")

        self.weAreRecording = false
        self.isSessionRunning = false

        println("Initializing assets library")

        self.library = ALAssetsLibrary()

        if let library = self.library {

            if library.videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL) {

                // error happens here, even though I am checking to see if it is nil before we get here
                self.library!.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL, completionBlock: { (outputURL, error) -> Void in

                    if error == true {

                        println("There was an error saving the video, which is: \(error.description)")
                    }
                    else {

                        NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(outputURL, error: nil)
                    }
                })

                println("Got pass saving the video")
            }
            else {

                println("Video is not compatible with saved photos album")
            }
        }
        else {

            println("Assets Library is nil!")
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {

        println("capture output: started recording to \(fileURL)")

        self.isSessionRunning = true
        self.weAreRecording = true
    }
```

I am holding the library as an optional property of the class.

Comment: What is targeted ios version?

Comment: The targeted ios version is ios 8

Comment: In iOS 8.0 and later, use the Photos framework instead of the Assets Library framework. The Photos framework provides more features and better performance for working with a user’s photo library. See Photos Framework Reference.

Comment: I assume that I would be using PHPhotoLibrary to access the library, but then how would I save the video at that point?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest/insertAssets:atIndexes: