# Going About Initializing PHAssetCollection Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am having some confusion on how to go about initializing the PHAssetCollection in my camera application correctly in order to save a video to the photo album. I am not trying to do anything with any video or picture in the photo album, I am simply just trying to save a captured video to the photo album through my camera application that is being developed around AVFoundation. Apple's documentation is scarce on this and all of the questions I have seen on here don't exactly address this. Should I even be using an asset collection for this task? Or is there a much simpler way using the Photos framework?

Here is the delegate functions that are called when the video starts and finishes recording

```
        println("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")

        self.weAreRecording = false
        self.isSessionRunning = false

        println("Getting moments in photo library")

        let results: PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Moment, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.AlbumRegular, options: nil)

        var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection?

//        SHOULD I EVEN BE DOING THIS??? IM NOT TRYING TO DO ANYTHING IN THE PHOTOS ALBUM

//        results.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (object, index, stop) -> Void in
//            
//            let assetCollection: PHAssetCollection = object as! PHAssetCollection
//            
//            momentsCount++
//            
//            blah blah blah
//            
//        }

        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {

            PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({

                let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(outputFileURL)

                let assetPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset

                // The problem is here, since I am not entirely sure how to go about initializing
                // The assetCollection correctly
                let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: assetCollection, assets: results)

                albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])

                }, completionHandler: {(success, error) in

                    if success {

                         NSLog("Adding video to Library -> %@", (success ? "Sucess" : "Error!"))
                    }
                    else {

                        println("There was an error saving the video")
                    }
            })

        })
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {

        println("capture output: started recording to \(fileURL)")

        self.isSessionRunning = true
        self.weAreRecording = true
    }
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you _want_ to do, so it is impossible to tell whether you doing it correctly.

Comment: i just want to save the video at the outputFileURL to the photo album using the Photos Framework. The issue I am having is in the comments of the code

Comment: But to _what_ photo album?

Comment: Moments. the targeted iOS version is 8

Comment: I just want to add it to the default moments album. I don't want to do anymore more or less with the video or anything inside of Moments

Comment: You can't add to Moments. It is an automatically constructed / organized way of looking at all the photos. Please state an actual album you want to add it to.

Comment: I guess that would be the Camera Roll then, just the default place where every other picture and video is usually stored. Thanks for that little tip btw, I would have never guessed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all your talk of a PHAssetCollection is a red herring. Since you just want to save a video into the camera roll, call `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

If for some reason you are reluctant to do that, then just save directly to the photo library, roughly like this (typed directly, not tested, may require some slight mods):

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(f)
    }, completionHandler: {
        (ok:Bool, err:NSError!) in
        // whatever
})
```

Comment: I tried using that before, I was also having issues with the ALAssetsLibrary and what not. Which is why I was advised to use this framework for iOS8 and above

Comment: Look man, I don't need the negativity. I am just explaining to you what I was advised to do and why, and what my issue is. You COULD actually help me out

Comment: Don't believe me, see this advice----http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340689/alassetslibrary-is-nil-cant-save-video-to-photo-album?noredirect=1#comment48775629_30340689

Comment: UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum does not involve the ALAssetsLibrary. It does work fine.

Comment: basically I had it right the entire time, I just had a bunch of useless nonsense there since I didn't really understand what is going on with this framework. Excuse my incompetence, this is my first time working with this framework and it has proven to be a bit challenging. SORRY if i have come off dumb to you and it offended you

Comment: Not at all, I just needed to ask questions in order to pare away the "useless nonsense" and understand what you were actually trying to do. I am a bit miffed about your response to my answer, though.